# Finding a specific string in a page with Beautifilsoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm working with bs4 and want to return the description of what specific built in Python functions do from the docs e.g. From this page for abs():

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Would return this:

> abs (x)
>
> Return the absolute value of a number. The argument may be a plain or long integer or a floating point number. If the argument is a complex number, its magnitude is returned.

I'm stuck on what I should be looking for apart from just the `<p>` element and how I can get that `<p>` element only and its text within. I know I could do a `findAll` search, but I want to do this without using the text that is in the page (e.g. As if the user doesn't know what the text is beforehand):

```
import requests, bs4, re

res = requests.get('https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html')
res.raise_for_status()
abs_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
abs_elems = abs_soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('^abs$'))
print abs_elems
abs_desc = abs_soup.select   # this is the part Im stuck on
print abs_desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the document of Python puts all functions inside `<dl class="function">`, and there's a `<dt id="name_of_the_function">` inside it.

So I'd suggest just use:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html')
abs_soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

print(abs_soup.find('dt', {'id': 'abs'}).find_next('dd').text)
```

Output:

> Return the absolute value of a number.  The argument may be a plain or long
>   integer or a floating point number.  If the argument is a complex number, its
>   magnitude is returned.

First, we use `abs_soup.find('dt', {'id': 'abs'})` to find the `<dt>` tag which has `abs` as it's `id`, and then we use `.find_next('dd')` to get the next `<dd>` tag after the `dt` tag.

Finally, use `.text` to get the text of that `<dd>` tag, however you can also use `.find_next('p').text)` instead, output is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would do like,

```
>>> func = abs_soup.select('dl.function')
>>> for i in func:
    if i.select('dt#abs'):
        print 'abs\n'
        print i.select('dd')[0].text


abs

Return the absolute value of a number.  The argument may be a plain or long
integer or a floating point number.  If the argument is a complex number, its
magnitude is returned.

>>>
```

or

Replace the last two lines of my code with this..

```
    print i.find('dt').text
    print i.find('dd').text
```